# AFNetworking 2.0, AFJSONResponseSerializer, AFHTTPResponseSerializer and concurrency

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I have a problem with AFNetworking 2.0.

I use this as singleton in my app.

Some requests have like type response a JSON Format others have a simple HTTP status.

So, in some request I have to use AFJSONResponseSerializer and in other I have to use AFHTTPResponseSerializer.

Some time I have a crash probably because in JSON responses is used AFHTTPResponseSerializer due to the concurrency ...

My requests are in this way:

```
[self GET:[self _userWithIdBuildUrl:userId] parameters:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

          AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc] init];
          self.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

          NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;

          if (httpResponse.statusCode == SmarfyGetUserProfileNoError) {
              //JSON data... In this point I have the crash
          }
          else {
///
          }
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

      }];
```

Ho can I fix?

Answer (score 2):

Put this:`AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc] init];
              self.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;` outside the block.